# Where is PHP echo implemented in the source?

Tags: php, echo, implementation, php-internals, language-construct

You can lookup built-in functions by searching for e.g. PHPAPI(stream_copy_to_stream) and find the implementation in ext/standard/streamsfuncs.c.

How to do that for a language construct like echo?

I found it is associated with T_ECHO in Zend/zend_language_parser.y but couldn't trace how it works from there.

Where does Zend Engine implement echo functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this example program:

```php
<?php echo 'Hello world!';
```

We can obtain the opcodes that the program is compiled to like so:

```sh
$ phpdbg7.4 -p /tmp/hello.php
function name: (null)
L1-2 {main}() /tmp/hello.php - 0x7fef35ea1000 + 3 ops
 L1    #0     EXT_STMT                                                                              
 L1    #1     ECHO                    "Hello world!"                                                
 L2    #2     RETURN<-1>              1
```

As you can see, echo is handled using a separate VM instruction: ZEND_ECHO. The handlers for each opcode is defined in [Zend/zend_vm_def.h](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_vm_def.h). Search for "ZEND_ECHO".